# Search form with responsive dropdown filter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need to make responsive dropdown filter in the following search form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 50px;
    }
    
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
      margin-top: -1px;
      padding: 6px 20px;
    }
    
    .input-group-btn .btn-group {
      display: flex !important;
    }
    
    .btn-group .btn {
      border-radius: 0;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
    
    .btn-group .btn:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    .form-horizontal .form-group {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    .form-group .form-control:last-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      #adv-search {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
        position: static !important;
      }
      .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 500px;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for snippets" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                      <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                        <option value="1">Featured</option>
                        <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                        <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                        <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Author</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The width of the dropdown should be as the width of its parent width as the default. 
It works fine in large device but the width varies in small devices.
you can get code snippet https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/advanced-dropdown-search. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any fiddle link pls

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not clean at all but it would solve your actual problem. Just add:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .dropdown-menu {
        width:calc(100vw - 30px);
        right:-39px;
    }
}
```

Notice that you will change a bootstrap class si it would affect any future dropdown menu you may include later. So better if you add your own class to the menu to use this code.